# What vim pattern matches a number which ends with dot?

Tags: vim, syntax, vim-syntax-highlighting

In PDP11/40 assembling language a number ends with dot is interpreted as a decimal number.
I use the following pattern but fail to match that notation, for example, `8.`:

```
syn match asmpdp11DecNumber /\<[0-9]\+\.\>/
```

When I replace `\.` with `D` the pattern can match `8D` without any problem. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my "end-with-dot" pattern? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression syntax is fine (well, you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`), but your `'iskeyword'` value does not include the period `.`, so you cannot match the *end-of-word* (`\>`) after it.

It looks like you're writing a syntax for a custom filetype. One option is to

```
:setlocal filetype+=.
```

in a corresponding `~/.vim/ftplugin/asmpdp11.vim` filetype plugin. Do this when the period character is considered a keyword character in your syntax.

Otherwise, drop the `\>` to make the regular expression match. If you want to ensure that there's no non-whitespace character after the period, you can assert that condition after the match, e.g. like this:

```
:syn match asmpdp11DecNumber /\<\d\+\.\S\@!/
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that a word is defined by vim as:

> A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
>   sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space
>   (spaces, tabs, ).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword'
>   option.  An empty line is also considered to be a word.

so your pattern works fine if whitespace follows the number. You may want to skip the `\>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your end-of-word boundary marker. Try this:

```
syn match asmpdp11DecNumber /\<[0-9]\+\./
```

Note that I have removed the `\>` end-of-word boundary. I'm not sure what that was in there for, but it appears to work if you remove it. A `.` is not considered part of a word, which is why your version fails.